# How to use namespace while inject models in node ts

Tags: node.js, typescript

Here is my `index.d.ts`

```
import { UserStruct } from "@/interface/user";
import { Model, Document} from 'mongoose'

declare global {
    namespace Models {
        export type userModel = Model<UserStruct & Document>;
    }
}
```

And here I am injecting models, `userController.ts`

```
import { UserStruct } from "@/interface/user";
import { Inject, Service } from "typedi";
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Service()
export class UserController  {

    constructor(
      @Inject('user')  private userModel//: Models.userModel,
    ) {};

    public async getUsers(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<{message: UserStruct[] | string, flag: boolean}>{
      try {
          const users = await this.userModel.find({});
          return {message: users, flag: true};
      } catch (error) {
          return {message: "Failed to get users", flag: false}
      }
    }
}
```

There is an error in compile time

```
  return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
  TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
  src/services/user/userController.ts:9:43 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Models'.

    @Inject('user')  private userModel: Models.userModel,
```

without `Models.userModel` this code `this.userModel.find({})` returns all records from `usesrModel`,

but when I define `userModel` type then throwing error while compile,
Note: when ctrl + click, navigating to the namespace declaration.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please paste all code with file name so i can understand the scenario else i paste ruff code for your reference

Comment: Sure, code updated,
issue is in line >>> @Inject('user')  private userModel: Models.userModel,